# Laravel: Route returns 404 page on form submit

Tags: laravel, controller, routes, laravel-5.3

**SOLVED**

web.php route:

```
Route::post('/admin/users/action', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@massAction',
    'as' => 'user.massAction'
]);
```

form:

```
<form id="users-form" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/admin/users/action') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    ...
</form>
```

UserController massAction method that doesn't get reached:

```
public function massAction(Request $request)
{
    $userIds = $request->input('users');
    $user = new User();

    switch ($request->input('mass-action')) {
        case 1:
            $user->deleteUser($userIds);
            $request->session()->flash('message-success', 'User(s) deleted!');
            break;
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

On form submit it should return back with a message, but it doesn't even reach the controller. Setting a breakpoint inside the method confirms that it doesn't reach it.

It just goes to /admin/users/action and returns 404 error, because this page doesn't exist. It should go to massAction method inside UserController and get redirected back to the page where form was submitted.

I am doing the same thing for products, attributes, etc. and it works fine. Only this route and method doesn't work. Other routes in the same UserController work.

Comment: If you have any route group you might require a `php artisan route:cache `

Comment: I don't have any groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in one of input fields. Have no idea why it didn't throw any errors or even reach the controller before.

This

```
<input class="entity-select" type="checkbox" name="specifications[{{ $user->id }}][id]" value="{{ $user->id }}">
```

needed to be like this

```
<input class="entity-select" type="checkbox" name="users[{{ $user->id }}[id]" value="{{ $user->id }}">
```

After changing it back to the wrong input field name it now throws out a error and also reached breakpoint in UserController. Maybe some view cache problem? If that is a thing.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use route() instead url().

Change action in  from url() to route() and check this out.

```
action="{{ route('user.massAction') }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need change your route like:

**web.php route:**

```
 Route::post('/admin/users/action','UserController@massAction')->name('user.massaction');
```

**form:**

```
<form id="users-form" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('user.massaction') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. As I said I already have massAction routes just like the one I posted, but for different controllers and they work, but this one doesn't for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Use put in the form after CSRF like this.

```html
@csrf
 @if(isset($category))
  @method('PUT')
 @endif
```